# Biggest Missing Features in Basecamp for Software Development Management & Collaboration

Tags: project-management, collaboration, basecamp

What features might our team find lacking if we adopted [Basecamp](http://basecamphq.com) for bug tracking, task tracking, external documentation, collaboration, and project management?

I've used the free version before and think that 37Signals makes excellent products - but I wanted to hear from you what the drawbacks might be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been using BaseCamp for 2 years now and found it to be an excellent general project information portal.  The ability to store documents, to-do tasks, and milestones with a living project view is pretty impressive.

Unfortunately their mantra of 'keep it simple' also has quite a few drawbacks in regards to capabilities:

1. the calendar is practically unusable for anything but the most basic of milestone tasks...  to keep track of our dev team we actually pulled together a custom Google Calendar implementation and use it for all developers and their tasks
2. BaseCamp is pretty difficult to use for bug tracking once you get a fair number in there assigned to various people - the ability to sort is lacking (beyond just turning people on and off) - you'll be much happier with a full Bug Tracking solution such as FogBugz.
3. For general project management Base Camp is fine but we've also found that we have external documents where we keep all the 'real' information - basically the multi-page specs and just upload them to Base Camp every once in a while.

Answer (score 4):

The last time I evaluated Basecamp I found one feature that was lacking was the ability to view workload or other information over several projects.  For exmaple, if I wanted to find out if Developer X had too much stuff to do or was spread too thin over several projects I could not figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

For me the missing feature was the ability to store my development stories in a way that worked for me.  I wanted a single template that I could use to generate every story and the ability to link stories together. Eventually, I ended up using a Wiki for this.  I didn't really have any need for to-do lists or time tracking stuff (this is handled separately by a company-wide app).

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to manage own documentation. Writeboards doesn't give you a good way of formatting your code and becomes unmanageable one you got more than 10 in a project. Message/Files gets messy if you got to many.

Answer (score 0):

Task estimates vs actuals is a big issue I've noticed.
Also being able to mark tiem as billed would be a nice feature it currnetly lacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can not export your files, they do not provide file api even.

So if you go out, you will get some work to take your files.

Recently I was helping a client to move 50 projects from Basecamp to Assembla. They said Assembla is better for project management and it has [more features](http://www.assembla.com/features).

Answer (score 0):

For me the missing feature was the ability to store my development stories in a way that worked for me. I wanted a single template that I could use to generate every story and the ability to link stories together. Eventually, I ended up using a Wiki for this. I didn't really have any need for to-do lists or time tracking stuff (this is handled separately by a company-wide app).

Answer (score 0):

With Basecamp, we were unable to track time spent over our tasks, a task could not be assigned to multiple people, could not maintain secrecy over important matters, could not keep messages as private, faced difficulty in proofing designs, could not freely chat with members of our team. So we went with ProofHub. It has got timesheets, To-do’s, casper mode, private messages, proofing tool and an inbuilt browser chat. We are just fine with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding a big gap with Basecamp to be user roles. It's impossible to have people on a project (other than a "client") who can only see certain to do lists. I'd like to be able to allocated roles for freelancers so they only have access to certain task lists within a project.